# Mapping of process name and application name using powershell

Tags: powershell, window, foreground

I need to track foreground application with application name in window machine.  I am using given code but it provide ProcessName not application name example ProcessName is "chrome" Apliication name is "Google Chrome". Either I get application name direclty  or i able to mapped Application name with process name.Please help me into this

```
  [CmdletBinding()]            
Param(            
)            
Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class UserWindows {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
}
"@            

try{        
$ActiveHandle = [UserWindows]::GetForegroundWindow()            
$Process = Get-Process | ? {$_.MainWindowHandle -eq $activeHandle} 
      
$Process | Select ProcessName, @{Name="AppTitle";Expression= {($_.MainWindowTitle)}} 
}catch{
Write-Error "Failed to get active Window details. More info:$_"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than give you the answer (since you may have more questions after) I will teach to to fish for yourself.

Lets say you have a variable and you want to see all of its properties you can get from it; run `$variable |get-member`
Now you see there are a lot of properties attached to your variable and you don't see any called "application name". So lets list all of the properties of this variable and see what gives us the value we are looking for.
For my example I will grab chrome to put into my variable so we are on the same page.
Here is the code I used to grab the variable to match what you would be working with (ignore this if you already have your variable you're working with).

```
$variable= Get-Process|? name -ilike chrome|select -first 1
```

Lets list all the properties

```
$variable|format-list *
```

Now we see there are 2 properties that list the name were looking for, Description and Product (for chrome either works, but i don't know which will work for your other use cases, possibly none).  Lets grab Product and use that for your code, substituting processname in the select statement (the statement that selects what properties to keep/show in that variable) with the Product Property... Now that you know how, you can change if need be =)

```
 [CmdletBinding()]            
Param(            
)            
Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class UserWindows {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
}
"@            

try{        
$ActiveHandle = [UserWindows]::GetForegroundWindow()            
$Process = Get-Process | ? {$_.MainWindowHandle -eq $activeHandle} 
      
$Process | Select Product, @{Name="AppTitle";Expression= {($_.MainWindowTitle)}} 
}catch{
Write-Error "Failed to get active Window details. More info:$_"
}
```